# Echo a multidimensional PHP array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-8

I want to return my nested array in a foreach loop. In this foreach loop I need to add a foreach, because it is variable how many accordions exist.

But I can't get it to load the data from the "accordion" array into the frontend.
There is always an error somewhere.

I can't describe it any better right now.

Save

This is my treatments.php file:

```
'treatments' => [
        [ /*  */
            'img' => asset('img/logos/Dermatologie_Dr_med_Aresu_Naderi_Nienstedten_Logo.png'),
            'title' => 'Klassische Dermatologie',
            'teaser' => 'Ein wesentlicher Bestandteil im Behandlungskonzept meiner Hautarztpraxis ist die ästhetische Dermatologie und Lasermedizin.',
            'pop-up' => 'derma',
            'accordion' => [
                [
              'title' => 'test',
              'content' => 'test2',
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'test',
                    'content' => 'test2',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

And this is my Frontend Blade Code:

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach( $treatments as $key => $value)
            <?php print_r($value) ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 py-5">
                <img class="w-100" src="{!! __($value['img']) !!}" alt="{!! __($value['title'])  !!}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 py-5">
                <span class="treatmentsHeadline">{!! __($value['title'])  !!}</span>
                <p class="pt-3">{!! __($value['teaser'])  !!}</p>
                <div class="pt-3">
                    <button class="button-naderi" href="#{!! __($value['pop-up']) !!}">Mehr erfahren</button>
                    <button class="button-naderi" href="#{!! __($value['pop-up']) !!}">Termin vereinbaren</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                @foreach($value as $acc)
                    <p>{!! __($acc['title']) !!}</p>
                @endforeach
        @endforeach
        <p class="footer-vh"></p>

    </div>
```

And this is the Array printed out:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any errors, and the printed data shows the accordion arrays. What exactly is the error?

Comment: Site crashes and get HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

`@foreach($value as $acc)` should be `@foreach($value['accordion'] as $acc)`

Comment: Yeah that was also my guess.. but site crashes with HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Is there any information in the laravel debug log (`storage/logs/`)?

Comment: You can try printing one key at a time from the array until it breaks. If you leave off the accordion, does it render as expected?

Comment: what works is `foreach($value[0]['accordion'] as $acc)` but i want all arrays not only the first one..

Answer (score 0):

I finaly got it!

```
@php
    $i = -1;
@endphp
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <img class="w-100" src="{!! __('treatments.derma') !!}" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container my-4">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach( $treatments as $key => $value)
            @php
                $i++;
            @endphp

            <div class="col-md-4 py-5">
                <img class="w-100" src="{!! __($value['img']) !!}" alt="{!! __($value['title'])  !!}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 py-5">
                <span class="treatmentsHeadline">{!! __($value['title'])  !!}</span>
                <p class="pt-3">{!! __($value['teaser'])  !!}</p>
                <div class="pt-3">
                    <button class="button-naderi" href="#{!! __($value['pop-up']) !!}">Mehr erfahren</button>
                    <button class="button-naderi" href="#{!! __($value['pop-up']) !!}">Termin vereinbaren</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            @isset($treatments[$i]['accordion'])

                @foreach($treatments[$i]['accordion'] as $key => $acc)

                    @php
                        print_r($acc);
                    @endphp
                    <p>{!! __($acc['title']) !!}</p>
                    <p>{!! __($acc['content']) !!}</p>

                @endforeach
            @endisset
        @endforeach
        <p class="footer-vh"></p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. It looks like all of the data was contained in a single element of the parent array.